# Returning com.badlogic.gdx.utils.Array<> of interfaces in Java

Tags: java, libgdx

I tried to declare method:

```
public Array<Shape2D> getShapes(){
...
}
```

And I got compiler error, that ';' is missing before round brackets. And `return` statement inside `getShapes` also is underlined with hint "Cannot return a value from method of void return type". I have to say I'm new in Java, but I assumed it would work. Can't I return Array<> type?

Answer (score 1):

In Java, the `Array.class` does not have type parameters.
What you can do is `Shape2D[]` instead which is an actual array of this specific type.
If your compiler sees a problem involving the void return, it's probably because `Array<Shape2D>` isn't the way you declare an array. Therefore, it thinks it's a void type method.

In this case, your code needs to look like this:

```
public Shape2D[] getShapes(){
...
}
```

If the Array.class is not the one mentioned below, then you may have imported something else.

Mention class:
*java.lang.reflect.Array*

Comment: Oh, sorry I didn't realise that I was using Array class from com.badlogic.gdx.utils I will update my question

Comment: ok my bad I didn't see the braces and was trying to define that in scope of other method... I'm going to delete this

Answer (score 0):

I didn't see the brackets and tried to declare method inside other method. Sorry for wasting your time.